# Set Div's Text to White

Tags: html, css, media-queries

I have this HTML Code below:

```
<div class="idnumber">101-03043</div>
```

CSS Code:

```
@media print {

   .idnumber
   {
       color: white;
   }
}
```

When I want to print my page , the div text's color is not white. Why is this happening?

Comment: use `!important` try `color: white!important;` because the css is overwritten

Comment: @TamilSelvan --> Still doesnt work :(

Comment: Ok. please clear a browser cache once and test it.

Comment: share your print preview screen

Answer (score 2, accepted):

White will usually be changed to a light gray or ignored for print. CSS backgrounds are also ignored. If you want the text to not be displayed, use `color: transparent`. Otherwise you'll need to elaborate on why you need the text white.

Comment: Thank you for explaining that white is ignored for printing. I tried printing it, and it appears white. What is lacking in print preview mode of google chrome is it ignores elements with white color making the appearance of my html different from what I expected. In my case, my div  has a parent element of green, making it greenish white.

Answer (score 1):

@media print is worked on **print preview mode**
your code is working perfectly for the clearance I change white to red

[image]